# SQL One value from whole result move to the top

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How despite of GROUP, ORDER and another parameters move one of select result rows to the top?
For example there on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb846/2)

Move row 3, with type Loren, to the top ?

Comment: Same problem as yesterdays http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156432/sorting-a-mysql-search-result-with-priority ?

Comment: @Hartmut Holzgraefe Thank you, "IF(id= '3', 0, 1), id" works perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is

```
select id, type, details from dummyTable ORDER BY IF(type = 'Test', 0, 1), id LIMIT 0, 5
```

[SqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb846/19)

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, type, details from dummyTable order by type="Lorem" DESC
```

and the [Sql Fiddle URL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb846/7)